# Git: When squashing or rebasing in a feature branch, why do you need to compare it to another branch like master?

Tags: git, github, rebase

I have a feature branch, `feature_account`.  It was branched off of `master` 2 months ago.  I made a number of commits in this branch and I want to squash them all into 1 commit while still in the feature branch.
Obviously, `master` has changed a bunch independently from the feature branch.   From my feature branch, if I type in `git rebase -i master`, I get merge conflicts from changes that are only in master  --- why does what is in master matter if I am only trying to combine all my commits from the feature branch into 1 commit?  I don't want to worry about master until I try to merge into master.  Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Yes: you're rebasing on master as it is now, instead of rebasing on master as it was when you created the branch. You can just use `git rebase -i <some-commit-hash>` or  `git rebase -i HEAD~3` if the commit on which you want to rebase is the 3rd in the history of the current one.

Comment: Yes, JB Nizet is right. When you typed `git rebase -i master` you explicitly *asked* to take `master` as the new base for the branch.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose the commit graph is like,

```
* b73f9ac (HEAD -> feature_account) f
* 5e77f54 e
* f6e5be0 d
| * c96a113 (master) c
| * f8132ea b
|/  
* bae8722 a
* 762077a initial commit
```

In `git rebase -i master`, the new base is `master`. But in your case, the new base should be `bae8722`, which is the fork point and the nearest common ancestor. It can be located by `git merge-base feature_account master`. In some more complicated situations, `git merge-base` may not work well and you need to find it out by other means.

To specify a new base explicitly, we can use `--onto <newbase>`,

```
git rebase -i --onto $(git merge-base feature_account master) master
```

or with a short form

```
git rebase -i --onto feature_account...master master
```

And then in the editor, change "pick" on the lines except the first one to "s". Save and exit. Edit the commit message and done.

To squash the new commits on `feature_account`, there is another method.

```
git checkout feature_account
# make the working tree clean if it's not
git stash -u
# here "feature_account...master" cannot be used 
git reset $(git merge-base feature_account master) --soft 
git commit
# restore the stashed changes if necessary
git stash apply --index
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume you made three commits to your `feature_account` branch.

When you typed in `git rebase -i master` you asked git to try to replay those three commits on top of the commit that `master` currently points to. You get to potentially fix conflicts three times (one for each commit you are rebasing).

You have indicated you wish to squash your `feature_account` into a single commit. One way to do this is to find the commit you started your work on and use that as your `git rebase -i <commit>`. With three commits, this command could be: `git rebase -i HEAD^^^`